# [only equal operator]what are the fast algorithms to find duplicate elements in a collection and group them?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, stl-algorithm

**Suppose we have a collection of elements, and these elements only have equal operator. So, it's impossible to sort them.**

how can you pick out those with duplicates and put them into each group with least amount of comparison? preferably in C++, but algorithm is more important than the language. For Example given {E1,E2,E3,E4,E4,E2,E6,E4,E3}, I wish to extract out {E2,E2}, {E3,E3}, {E4,E4,E4}. what data structure and algorithm you will choose?

**EDIT**

My scenario, if binary data 1 is equal to binary data 2 we can say these two elements are identical. But, only **=** and **!=** is logical

```
element 1:

4 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Kids 5 0 R /Count 1 >>
stream
.....binary data 1....
endstream
endobj

element 2:

5 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Kids 5 0 R /Count 1 >>
stream
.....binary data 2....
endstream
endobj
```

Comment: Do you really need to group them, or can you just count how many occurrences of each there are? I mean, if they are equal, there is no need to store them multiple times, does it?

Comment: Are the element's hashable? You can map a hash to a list. Element's with the same hash can then be place into the corresponding list. This would only require visiting each element once.

Comment: @Luc Touraille I have the array at hand, what I want to do is group equal elements.

Comment: @greatwolf no, each element is independent.

Comment: @greatwolf Typically hash codes used for set implementation are not collision resistant

Comment: @Triumphant Can you clarify what it means for two elements to be equal? Is it logical equality? Can two elements have different byte layout but still be equal?

Comment: I guess for any algorithm beyound brute force we need more information about the elements.

Comment: @greatwolf please see the updated info.

Comment: Why do you only have '=' ? surely '<' & '>' would be easy to define/overload ?

Comment: @NWS: The class may be outside your control. Doesn't matter, though, as `std::sort` can take a predicate, or you could specialize `std::less<T>` to not use `T::operator<`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sufficient to find any arbitrary predicate `P` such that `P(a,a)==false`, `P(a,b) && P(b,a)==false`, `P(a,b) && P(b,c)` implies `P(a,c)` and `!P(a,b) && !P(b,a)` implies `a == b`. Less-then satisfies this property, as thus greater-then. But they're far from the only possibilities.

You can now sort your collection by predicate `P`, and all elements which are equal will be adjacent. In your case, define `P(E1,E2)=true, P(E2,E3)=true`, etc.

Comment: @MSalters... I didn`t get this math. Can you please explain this for my knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Krishna: I basically say that any ordering will work if it's sufficiently similar to <. It must keep equal elements together, so the predicate must return false for equal elements. It can't insert other elements in the middle of a range of equal elements, and when ordering  unequal elements a and b the result must be consistent even if it's done via an intermediate c. As an example, you can sort  numbers in reverse order of digits, so 21 comes before 12. Still all 21's will go together.

Answer (score 2):

For your answer, though I am not 100% sure that you want this is only.

If you want good algo try `Binary search tree` creation. as it is a group,and according to `BST properties` you can easily group elements.

For Example

```
BST()
{
    count = 0;
    if(elementinserted)
        count = 1;
    if(newelement == already inserted element)
    {
        count++;
        put element in array upto count value;
    }
}
```

I hope this explanation can help you.

Comment: For binary search trees you need a relational comparison (less-than). A pure equality comparison is not sufficient.

Comment: @Triumphant...In worst case Insertion and search is O(n) and in average case Insertion and Search is O(log n).

Answer (score 2):

If all you have is an equality test, you have no hope.

Suppose you have a situation where each element is unique.  And another where only two elements are duplicates.

There are `n(n+1)/2` of the second type.  Each can only be distinguished from the first by a particular comparison.  Which means in the worst case you must do all `n(n+1)/2` comparisons: exhastive search over all pairs.

What you need to do is to figure out what else you can really do, as equality only is exceedingly rare.