# How to calculate a number which is not present in given ranges

Tags: c, algorithm

I have to print the numbers between 1 and n which are not present in the given subsets. All the subsets will fall between 1 and n. The subsets are always in ascending sequence.
for e.g. n=300 and the subsets given by user are (30 to 70) (50 to 100) (150 to 200) and (250 to 300) then I need print the output as: numbers from 1 to 29, 101 to 149, 201 to 249.

My approach for this is:

1. Take each number from 1 to n and verify if it's present in any of the given subsets
2. If it's not present in any of the given subsets then print that number.
3. Else continue.

The questions I have are:

1. Is there any more elegant approach than this?
2. And how can we implement this in C language. (I am not asking for the line by line code.I just want to know how do we represent the subsets in the C language and how do we search for the missing number in the subsets.)

Comment: see the accepted answer...... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740402/only-equal-operatorwhat-are-the-fast-algorithms-to-find-duplicate-elements-in/17740814#17740814

Comment: You can post your best effort of coding the problem here and get answers to questions.

Comment: Are the "ranges" guaranteed to not overlap?

Comment: @Nik the ranges can overlap with each other..

Comment: please see my updated answer...I'm quite beginning in C, but is this close to your intention?

Comment: @krrishna: Are the subsets complete (ie `30 to 70` means all numbers from 30 to 70) ? And if not, are they provided sorted ?

Answer (score 2):

If n is fixed, i.e. it is not to be entered by the user, but can be hardcoded, you could define an array such as this:

```
#define N 300
int my_set[N + 1];
```

then initialize the whole array with `1`, meaning "this number must be printed".
Then, when the user enters the subsets, set the corresponding array elements to `0`.
Finally scan the array and print the index of the elements whose value is still `1`.

Comment: Exactly that was my another approach .But do you see that it has less complexity than what I have given in my original post ?

Comment: @krrishna To compare complexities (BTW, in which sense? Time? Space?) you should have posted real code or a carefully described algorithm.

Comment: You'll be running into problems for a really large `N`.

Comment: It is no better than the OP's first approach as you are anyhow comparing each index to be printed or not

Comment: @alk Well, the OP didn't give much context, and didn't want a "line-by-line" solution. Mine was a hint for what seemed a programming exercise or assigment. Talking about `malloc`, bit-fields, or bit packing into `ints` seemed overkill.

Comment: Even bit packing won't help from a certain size of `N` on. I wanted to express that an approach using bitmaps solve such problems only for a definite maximum value of `N`. Imagine `N` being 2^256 or even larger.

Comment: @Saksham Explain your meaning of "*better*"; and I didn't claim it was better, since to compare two approaches you must first set an optimality criterion, which was not given. The OP asked for a more "elegant" approach, and mine *is* another approach (whether it is more elegant, it's a matter of taste too).

Comment: @alk Fair point. That's true, and it's worth to point out (but then it is better for the records to state what problems, i.e. some form of memory exahustion). As I told Saksham, I picked on the word "elegant" by the OP: since he was talking about sets, the technique I showed is somewhat elegant IMO for small sets, and easy to implement. It may also make the code cleaner, separating some concerns.

Comment: Referring "*eleganties*": easy is "*elegant*" in terms stability and developement costs, "*elegant*" in terms of science IMHO means all-embrassing. As this seem to be for educational puspose I'd assume the latter meaning ... ;-)

Comment: @alk Oh, well, I was careful to quote the word "elegant", since it has so many subjective facets that it may easily be used as flame-bait. And I don't want to start flame wars! :-) (for example, "elegance" as seen by engineers vs. mathematicians ... you'll see flying unicorns! :-)

Answer (score 1):

An approach would be(Just giving the pseudo code):

1. Sort the sets in ascending order of the first element in the pair.(Which are already sorted for your case)
2. Take an array and insert the elements in it as: 0, p(1,1),p(1,2),p(2,1),p(2,2)....
   (which will be 0,30,70,50,100,150,200,250,300...for OP's case)
3. Loop through the array while incrementing the counter( taking it i) by 2.
4. `if(arr[i]<arr[i+1])`   loop from `arr[i]` to `arr[i+1]` and print elements. else while incrementing the counter by 2, go to the element which is larger than the `arr[i+1]`th element.

For eg: if the array is: `0, 2, 5000, 3, 50, 60, 100, 6000, 6050`; from 5000, incrementing by 2, you will jump to 6050.

The advantage of this approach being is that it doesn't compare each of the value in the range to print it or not which is a big performance boom over checking for each number in the range to print or not to. Creating the initial array in C would be a bit difficult(which is quite easy in c++).

**NOTE:**: It might look unclear and difficult initially due to explanation in short but is not.

Comment: You perhaps should switch from pseudo code with explanations to real code. At least me I'm curious! ;-)

Comment: @alk I do not code in `C` as to do it efficiently, I need STL Containers

Comment: @alk BTW I have tested for a few cases and it is giving desired results

Comment: Yes, I think I got it. Nice and "elegant": +1

Comment: This is nice and elegant and with a small optimization and a space-time tradeoff runs in O(MlogM) where M is the number of subsets. The solution provided in the question is O(NM) so this is quite and improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you can follow.
Suppose you are given

**Range** as [1 to N], where N can be variable(input from user)/constant(fixed already).

**Subsets** as Ai[ai, bi], where 1<=i<=k. ie you have k subsets with ai being the lower boundary and bi being the upper boundary.

Now start creating tree with first node as [1,N]. At a given time during the execution of the algorithm, In the tree, each **leaf node** represent the range of number which is not covered by any of the given subset, ie you must print the range of numbers for all the leaf nodes.

**INITIAL CONDITION**
To start with Tree has only one leaf node [1,N]. i.e since we have not processed any subsets yet so we must print all numbers between 1 to N.

**TERMINATION CONDITION**
At the end of algorithm tree will contain many leafs. Each leaf will represent range of numbers not covered by any subsets. so you must print those numbers as output.

**Algorithm:**

```
STEP 1: Creating the Tree   
For i = 1 to k  //process for all given subsets
{
    For every leaf node in current tree
    {
        //Let [x,y] is the current leaf node being processed
        1. if(ai>=x && bi<=y) //subset being processed lie inside the leaf being
           processed.
           create nodes [x,ai-x] and [bi+1,y] and attach as child of the leaf node       
           being processed.

        2. if((x<=ai<y) && (bi>y)) //subset overflows towards right
           create a node [x, ai-1] and attach as child to the current leaf node being
           processed.

        3. if((ai<x) && (x<bi<=y)) //subset overflows towards left
           create a node [bi+1, y] and attach as child to the current leaf node being
           processed.
    }
}

STEP 2: Printing the output
//Now the leaf nodes indicate the numbers to be printed.
For each leaf node [x,y] of the resulting tree
{ 
    //you will get some leaf node with x>y
    if(x<=y)
         print the numbers in range [x,y].
}
```

Comment: Just posted the pseudo code. If you find any difficulty let me know I will post some example runs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about C but something like this? `n` is given as the first command line argument, followed by the ranges, separated by spaces.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i, j, count = 1, n, lBound, uBound;

    sscanf (argv[1], "%i", &n);

    for (i = 2; i < argc; i += 2)
    {
        sscanf (argv[i], "%i", &lBound);

        sscanf (argv[i + 1], "%i", &uBound);

        if (lBound > count)
            for (j = count; j <= lBound - 1; j++)
                printf("%d ",j);

        count = uBound + 1;
    }

    if (count < n)
        for (j = count; j <= n; j++)
            printf("%d ",j);
}
```

Output:

```
C:\c>notPresent 100 20 80
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91
92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100

C:\c>notPresent 100 20 80 60 90
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```